# MongoDB string search

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have one collection named: article
currently user collection has following attributes:

1. title
2. description
3. tags
4. seo_tile

Lets consider one document first

```
  {
   title: yoga for beginners
   description: blah blah...
   tags: blah blah...
   seo_title: yoga.for.beginners OR yoga-for-beginners
  }
```

generating seo_title by replacing spaces of title with .{dot} and adding one unique id if it is already exist in article collection as yoga.for.beginners.86ht7

Now comes to data retrieval, I am writing a query as:

db.article.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".*yoga.for.beginners.*"}});

Now tell me the difference in terms of query optimizing if I store seo_title by replacing spaces of title with -{hyphen}

Case 1:   yoga.for.beginners

```
db.article.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".*yoga.for.beginners.*"}});
```

Case 2:   yoga-for-beginners

```
db.article.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".*yoga-for-beginners.*"}});
```

Which one is more optimize way of doing the above thing?

Comment: It makes no difference (other than the fact that a `.` needs to be escaped to be searched - which you did not do in the first example). If you're not using an anchored regex search (which you're not), every document must be searched. You might want to look into the beta full text search of MongoDb or an actual full text search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Theres no difference but you should escape the dots

```
db.article.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".*yoga\.for\.beginners.*"}});
```